# jQuery collection issue

Tags: html, css, collections

I've got a problem whit my script. I have a list of my file structure (so this built by a recursive php function and I do not know how many subfiles or subdirectories do I have). By default, the folders are hidden and when the user click on the folder, the first containing ul will slide down.
The problem is that the $('.folder') selector select the subfolder and then the parent folder and so on, because every folder got the same folder class. So when I click on an opened folder's folder the clicked folder will open, but the parent folder will close. I hope the description was clear enough.

Here is some code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="file">file1.txt</li>
 <li class="folder">
  folder1
    <ul>
      <li class="folder">
        folder2
          <ul>
            <li class="file">fileA.txt</li>
            <li class="file">fileB.txt</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="file">file1A.txt</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="file">file2.txt</file>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.folder').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul:first').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

So, when I click on folder2 the folder2's ul will slide down but after it the folder1 will slide up because both folder2 and folder1 in the collection of $('.folder').

What is the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.folder').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul:first').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Try using `e.stopPropagation()`. It prevents action being performed on PARENT.

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/5dtDm/)

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks, it works fine. I just heard first time about this stopPropagation(), but I will remember it so long :).

Comment: @VargaTamas, don't forget to mark Aspiring Aqib's answer correct if it's the best solution (which it appears to be).